# Unknown Entity namespace alias 'PirastruFormBuilderBundle'

Tags: symfony, entity, symfony-sonata

It has been now 2 days that i'm looking for a solution to this error but in vain :

> Unknown Entity namespace alias 'PirastruFormBuilderBundle'

in fact i installed the sonata form builder with sonata page bundle using the composer but i don't know why i'm getting this error.

i don't know which part of codes should i copie here so please don't hesitate to ask me for it

```
sonata_form_builder:
    resource: '@PirastruFormBuilderBundle/Controller/FormBuilderController.php'
    type:  annotation
```

Thanks !!

EDIT

when i run this : php app/console config:dump-reference

> PirastruFormBuilderBundle           | pirastru_form_builder     |

and when i run this : php app/console doctrine:mapping:info i got

> [Exception]   You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities
>   according to the current configuration. If you have entities or
>   mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.

well i managed to solve the problem ! i had just to add a getManager in my FormBuilderBlockService

Comment: try command php : app/console config:dump-reference

Comment: '+-------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| Bundle name                         | Extension alias           |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| MonologBundle                       | monolog                   |
| PirastruFormBuilderBundle | pirastru_form_builder   |'


i got this

Comment: Try php app/console doctrine:mapping:info, please make edits in your post, for a weel formatted string !!!

Comment: You must map you entities (model), auto_mapping : true from config.yml. Have a look to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974519/symfony-what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-mapping-and-auto-generate-proxy-classes

Comment: doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            portail:
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:

It's on true

Comment: oh thank you i just found it !!
i had the add a getmanager
**if ($formBuilderId) {
            $formBuilderId = $this->container->get('doctrine')
                ->getManager('portail')
                ->getRepository('Pirastru\FormBuilderBundle\Entity\FormBuilder')
                ->findOneBy(array('id' => $formBuilderId));
        }

Comment: It's OK for you ?

Comment: I will make a correct answer, you can accept it ?

Comment: Yeah i accept :)

Comment: I've wrote a answer, can you please accept it ?

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: You can accept on answer like this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be caused by some (mis)configurations :

**Bundle**

```
app/console config:dump-reference
```

This command let you know if the Bundle is referenced.

**Mapping**

```
app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

This command let you know if the Bundle is mapped.

It's typically a mapping issue :

> Unknown Entity namespace alias '***Bundle'

The better solution is to add auto_mapping to true in `config.yml`, like this :

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
```

But it can be solved by others way, you can have a look to : [Symfony : What is the meaning of auto_mapping and auto_generate_proxy_classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974519/symfony-what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-mapping-and-auto-generate-proxy-classes)

Best regards,