# Missing Symfony AppBundle mappings after adding a new bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use a new entity manager in Symfony 2.7 Project, 
I created a new bundle and I added a new database and entity manager.

But for some reasons the configuration seems to be incorrect for AppBundle the default Symfony bundle.

I tried many solutions available in StackOverflow none of them worked:
This is my error:

```
  [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]                  
  Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'.
```

This is my config

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping : true
            mappings:
                AppBundle:
                    type: xml
                    dir: 'Resources/config/doctrine'
                FOSUserBundle:
                    type: xml
                    dir: 'Resources/config/doctrine-mapping'

        mailfun:
            connection: mailfun
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            mappings:
                MailFunBundle:
                    type: xml
                    dir: 'Resources/config/doctrine'
```

The solutions that I tried and didn't worked are:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12616261/1765681

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29774930/1765681

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41136079/1765681

[Symfony doctrine auto_mapping Unrecognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634625/symfony-doctrine-auto-mapping-unrecognized/37652091#37652091)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42949150/1765681

edit: added AppKernel.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
            new Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
            new Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\LexikFormFilterBundle(),
            new cspoo\Swiftmailer\MailgunBundle\cspooSwiftmailerMailgunBundle(),
            new FelDev\MailFunBundle\MailFunBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),

        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'), true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: That error - when exactly are you getting it?  Is it from a console command, a controller action?

Comment: From console in dev mode

Comment: Which command specifically?  What does your AppKernel look like?

Comment: Is a new command inside the new bundle, but I tried to run inside the other bundle and the same error happens

Comment: I don't see another bundle of yours besides AppBundle.  What was the other bundle before?  What is the exact console command you are running?  Did you clear the cache?  etc.

Comment: Is this   new FelDev\MailFunBundle\MailFunBundle(), I'm running a new command just to read and save events from mailgun api, but when I'm saving the events the ORM exception is thrown

Comment: What is the console command?

Comment: the command is fine is the config for appbundle what is missing

Comment: I think it's probably entity namespace error.